# Angular JS HTML5 Validation

Tags: html, forms, validation, angularjs

I have a form that I have used the `required tag` on my inputs - this works fine but on my submit button I have `ng-click="visible = false"` that hides the form when the data is submitted.

How could I make it so that its only set to false if all the validation is correct?

App.js

```
 $scope.newBirthday = function(){

        $scope.bdays.push({name:$scope.bdayname, date:$scope.bdaydate});

        $scope.bdayname = '';
        $scope.bdaydate = '';

    };
```

HTML:

```
 <form name="birthdayAdd" ng-show="visible" ng-submit="newBirthday()">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="bdayname" required/>
        <label>Date:</label>
        <input type="date" ng-model="bdaydate" required/>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="visible = false" type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give a name to the form that FormController will be exposed in the nearest controller scope by its name. So in your case say you have a structure something like

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <!-- more stuff here perhaps -->
    <form name="birthdayAdd" ng-show="visible" ng-submit="newBirthday()">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="bdayname" required/>
        <label>Date:</label>
        <input type="date" ng-model="bdaydate" required/>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="onSave()" type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
</div>
```

Now in your controller

```
function MyController($scope){
    // the form controller is now accessible as $scope.birthdayAdd

    $scope.onSave = function(){
        if($scope.birthdayAdd.$valid){
            $scope.visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If the input elements inside the form are valid then the form will be valid. Hope this helps.